# Wordpress on a cloud, registration issue,

Tags: wordpress, azure, sendgrid, user-registration

**Hello world!**

Heres my issue, Im running a site on a azure cloud network, since natively azure does not support SMTP and wordpress member registration is built around this (as well as most to all plugins) so when it comes time for members to register, it all works well up until its time they should receive their activation key through email... and they dont. If by obtaining a sendgrid account through host, parsing info from sendgrid host app to my WP sendgrid app setting, Will it the allow the delivery of "welcome" and delivery of mentioned activation keys through emails to members upon registering? Im stumped on how to fix this issue, Im quite sure this is the fix.

ALso, if this wold be the answer to my problem, where would meber info be sent... To my WP user tab or wold there be a third party involved in maintaning this database.

Thank you for yout ime,
-Erawkz

Comment: This is unrelated to programming, sound more like a case for their help desk.

Comment: Fair enough, solved the issue! yay, thanks user 131.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I run sendgrid for my wordpress site it replaces the WP mail function make sure you read the installation instructions carefully it requires you to modify your user.ini file